# MS SQL listing out data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm looking for a MS SQL query to list out data from ONE field in a database, but if some of the data is the same it should only list it once.

Is there a way to do this?

Let me give an example, we are having a database with a field called category and in category is the following data:
- Boat
- Car
- Boat
- Car
- Bus

What it should list out would then be

-Boat
-Car
-Bus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT DISTINCT` will do exactly what you want;

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM mytable
```

[A very simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/622593/1).